# Is It possible to run a custom seeding method from the package manager console?

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

When you run Update-Database in the package manager console it runs a seed process. Is it possible to run a different command to run some other seeding command?

Something like:

```
Seed-Test-Data
```

Which would seed some test data to a developers local database.

I don't want to run this command in the normal seed method because that would run on the production database when the migrations ran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the regular seed, but check what server the context is using and act accordingly. Either white list the dev databases or black list the prod servers:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Database.Connection.DataSource != "ProductionServer")
        {
            if (!context.MyTable.Any())  // If table is empty, seed it...
            {
                context.MyTable.AddOrUpdate(
                  p => p.ID,
                       new MyTable{ ID = 1, FullName = "Mary Peters" },
                       new MyTable{ ID = 2, FullName = "Mike Lambson" },
                       new MyTable{ ID = 3, FullName = "Steve Miller" }
                );
            }


        }
        ...
    }
}
```

You could also add a setting to check the environment in your web.config:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Environment"] == "DEV")
{
    ...
}
```